# The new auto-updater for vote counts is really annoying

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, notifications, live-refresh

It's been confusing me for too long already. Things I've noticed:

- When there are multiple votes being cast on the same post in succession of each other, it constantly keeps flashing back and forth between a bunch of numbers. I just want to see **what the current count** is. I really don't care what the previous count was or what it's changing to and from.
- While the vote count is doing all this flashing nonsense, I am **unable to click on it to expand the vote count**. Making me wait for the script to finish it's business isn't very friendly.
- Once you've expanded the vote count and then the script re-updates the post with the new vote count, you are **unable to then re-expand the vote count** to view it again. This is *especially* frustrating when you *just* expanded it and then the vote count updates immediately afterwards. This means you have to reload the page to expand the count, unless you have magical eyes that caught the numbers in the split-second it was shown.

These issues may not be so prevalent on old, inactive posts where there's not a whole lot of voting activity. But on newer posts where there *is* activity it seems to be doing more irritating than being helpful.

**My Solution:**

Use a notification box similar to what's already in place on the home screen. Rather than "there are *x* posts with new activity" or whatever, put a popup somewhere that says "there have been additional votes cast, click here to reload the vote counts" or "there are new comments which have been posted, click here to load them." Give us the **ability** to reload them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues raised here that will be fixed in the next build.  Post scores will no longer be animated for every score change.  If there is already animation happening and the post score changes value during the animation it will not re-animate the score.  This should reduce the amount of perceived flashing.

The re-expanding of the votes was a simple bug.  The intent was to always rebind the vote count expansion if you had the proper reputation.